# trigger to update particular column in table A after update on table A

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I am using postgresql and I want to update a column by summing up other column in the table.

> EX: table name is A. When col1 or col2 or any column value in table A
>   is updated then the value of col6 should also be updated as
>   col6=(col1+col2+col3)

for this i have written a update trigger as below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_total2() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $_$
BEGIN
    UPDATE hr_contract SET "x_TOTAL"=(NEW.x_othr_allow+NEW.x_med_allw+NEW."x_LTA"+NEW.wage+NEW.supplementary_allowance) WHERE id = OLD.id;
    RETURN OLD;
END $_$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';


CREATE TRIGGER hr_contract_after_update
    AFTER update ON hr_contract

    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_total2();
```

It is giving error as below..

```
ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."res_users" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR SHARE OF x"
SQL statement "UPDATE hr_contract SET "x_TOTAL"=(NEW.x_othr_allow+OLD.x_med_allw+OLD."x_LTA"+OLD.wage+OLD.supplementary_allowance) WHERE id = OLD.id"
PL/pgSQL function update_total_result() line 3 at SQL statement
SQL statement "UPDATE hr_contract SET "x_TOTAL"=(NEW.x_othr_allow+OLD.x_med_allw+OLD."x_LTA"+OLD.wage+OLD.supplementary_allowance) WHERE id = OLD.id"
```

Any help is really very useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check if any thing has changed on that row, and set the value of field x_TOTAL if any:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_total2() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $_$
  BEGIN
--Check if any of columns has been updated:
  if tg_op='UPDATE' and  old <> new then 
    NEW."x_TOTAL"= NEW.x_othr_allow+NEW.x_med_allw+NEW."x_LTA"+NEW.wage+NEW.supplementary_allowance);
  end if;

RETURN NEW;
END $_$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

--Associate triger to table on BEFORE update events
CREATE TRIGGER hr_contract_after_update
    before update ON hr_contract

    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_total2();
```

[Trigger documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with postgresql syntax but the problem is that you are doing a recursive update. Your function update_total2 must not use UPDATE to the same table being updated on the trigger.

Please check documentation for details, all you have to do in the trigger itself is something like:

```
FOR EACH ROW
    NEW.x_TOTAL = NEW.x_othr_allow + NEW.x_med_allw  + NEW."x_LTA" + NEW.wage + NEW.supplementary_allowance
```

Comment: there is no update statement! no need for where cause. see revised answer.